# Hadoop CouchDB Elastic Search

Tags: hadoop, couchdb, mapreduce, elasticsearch

I have already installed CouchDB (ver 1.1.0), Elastic Search (0.17.6) on my Fedora. I want now to install Hadoop Map/reduce (http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/) and Hadoop DFS (http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/) on this machine but I wonder whether there is a conflict and problem between them? Can Elastic Search and CouchDB function properly?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for conflict. I wouldn't put all of these on one production machine, because of the performance issues, but if it's your development box, then go ahead.

- CouchDB is project written in Erlang that uses Mozilla's SpiderMonkey for executing Javastcipt queries
- Hadoop is pure Java and will not conflict with above in any way.
- Elasticsearch and Lucene are also Java, and it wont conflict with Hadoop because theirs startup scripts will define specific classpaths, so multiple installed versions of the same libraries shouldn't create an issue.